# Using "Regexp Escape" and "should match" in Robot Framework

Tags: regex, robotium, robotframework

I am trying to learn the Robot Framework, I am trying to match Regular expressions like this

```
TC should match
    ${escaped} =    Regexp Escape   Hello World
    Should Match    ${Hello World}  ${escaped}
```

Where ,
${Hello World} is Hello World (declared in the variables table)

When i run this command I am getting this error.
" 'Hello World' does not match 'Hello\ World' ". What am I doing wrong?. Thanks in advance.
Also, I am trying to match things like [a-z]* or s+ d+. I am not able to do that. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/BuiltIn.html?r=2.8.1#Regexp%20Escape):

> Returns each argument string escaped for use as a regular expression.

So Regexp Escape KW forms such a string from the given string that it can be used as a regular expression. "`Hello World`" becomes "`Hello\ World`", which of course will not match with "Hello World" because other one contains \ character.

If you use `Should Match Regexp` the test will pass.

Comment: what if I want to use 'Hello World' itself as RE?. I mean whats the whole point of inserting a "\" in creating the pattern?. What good will it do?

Comment: Should Match does not use regexp, it is more like small subset of regexp, Should Match Regexp does use regexp. Regexp Escape is just a wrapper for python re.escape() http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html which says "Return string with all non-alphanumerics backslashed; this is useful if you want to match an arbitrary literal string that may have regular expression metacharacters in it."

Comment: Seems like we are the only people on SOF using Robot FrameWork :P. Thanks BTW.

Comment: How about Regexp such as ^.*My something \(yeah\).*  ? these are not matched